# Angular Attribute Directives in IE8 not rendering

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

Has anyone run into the issue where attribute directives using templateURL does not render in IE8?  I have run it through Fiddler, and the HTML templates are loading, but just don't get rendered into the tags where the attributes are set.  There are also no javascript errors.

The code works perfectly in IE9+, and other modern browsers.

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: none.  The tags just end up empty.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: 1.3.8. I know they dropped IE8 support, but I have already followed the guide to resolve the javascript errors caused... just not sure what else is causing the directives to not render.